# How to get a token from AWS Cognito by providing user/pass using REST API endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

How to get AWS token form by providing username and password of a configured user?
What I want to do is to have a URL that accepts user/pass as a post params and returns a token. 
None of three "Allowed OAuth Flows" [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html) does this or any other URL

**EDIT:** 
How do I do that from Postman ?  I am looking for something like :

- Call aws url and provide user/pass for one of the users in the pool
- AWS returns a token
- Include the token with every request to the resource server
- Resource server validates the token

Answer (score 0):

1.
Before you are able to request a login you first have to receive temporary credentials by calling [GetCredentialsForIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html).

You need those credentials to sign your actually login request.

2.
Now start an [InitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html) with AuthFlow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH.

Send a POST request to this URL:
https://cognito-idp.< REGION >.amazonaws.com/
(You can find your regional endpoints [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#endpoint-tables), scroll down to "Amazon Cognito Your User Pools")

Containing the following body:

```
{"ClientId":"<CLIENT_ID>",
"AuthFlow":"USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
"AuthParameters":
{"USERNAME":"<USERNAME>","PASSWORD":"<PASSWORD>"}}
```

And send the necessary [Common Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html) in the header.
(Sign with temporary credentials)

I suggest to use an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) because setting all needed parameters can be tricky.

Comment: I want to be able to do that from POST man, is there a way to do it?

Comment: I will try it and see if it works, and come back to you :)

Comment: Where did you get the URL from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OAuth 2.0 compliant [TOKEN Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) to achieve this use-case.

Comment: Nowhere in docs says where to provide the password and username